# How to use pdfMake in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, pdfmake

I am using `pdfMake` to generate pdf in `AngularJS`. I have downloaded the bower package.

Do I need to inject it to my modules and controllers before I can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the references and you can use it as follows,

```
$scope.downloadPdf = function() {
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
};
```

Find this **[`repository`](https://github.com/sajeetharan/angularPDFgenerator)** which has a demo with pdfMake and angularjs

Comment: Thank you sir, I added the references in my index html and it worked! :)